# Parse the callback URL from foursquare?

Tags: ruby, url, foursquare, access-token

I am trying to parse the URL returned from the foursquare api (the callback URL) the problem is that the request comes in this format

```
0.0.0.0:4567/foursquare#access_token=KCZGA4JIR4N3QXXAASZTZRYWHU2TYJITM53LARSKHRVFPHQ
```

as you can see that hashtag is breaking havoc in my code because is nowhere to be found using `request.url` or the whole request object for that matter.

Has anyone solved this? I am not trying to authenticate, I already do that from inside the iOS app.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-validations'
require 'dm-timestamps'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-ar-finders'

# where foursquare sent us after authorization
get "/foursquare" do
    puts "Receiving ..." + request.url
end
```

Comment: No, I can't see that the hashtag is breaking havoc in your code, because you haven't shown us your code. Can you share a snippet of what you've tried?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, using the `request` object, just returns the `0.0.0.0:4567/foursquare` part

Comment: How are you fetching it? Many libraries have a `request` object. You'll get better answers if you provide a code snippet.

Comment: I am not using any libraries, but I included the source code above now in the quesitons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you want to hear, but a quick fix would be let your Sinatra (assuming that given your port number) do the authentication instead of the iOS app. This way you can take advantage of the omniauth-foursquare gem, https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-foursquare/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/foursquare.rb, which will do most of the parsing for you.

According to Foursquare's API page, https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client, they recommend doing a web-based authentication too.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to mark this as the answer anyway :) and for everyone to see what NOT to do in this case :) thanks